# GCD in a PID persists in extension domains

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be subring of integral domain $S.$ Suppose $R$ is $\text{PID}.$ Let $a\in R$ be a greatest common divisor of $r_1,r_2$ in $R$. ($r_1,r_2 \in R$, not both zero). Could anyone advise me on how to prove $a$ is greatest common divisor of $r_1,r_2$ in $S?$

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Hint: there exists $s_1,s_2\in R$ such that $a=r_1s_1+r_2s_2$ and also notice that $a|r_1,r_2$ in $R$.

Comment: Thank you. This means $(a) = (r_1) + (r_2)$ in $R$ and hence $(a) = (r_1) +(r_2)$ in $S.$ Let $(z) \subseteq S$ such that $r_1,r_2 \in (z).$ For any $x,y \in S, \ r_1x+r_2y \in (z),$ so $(a) \subseteq (z)$ in $S.$

Now, if $R$ is $\text{UFD}$ but not $\text{PID},$ how do I disprove the statement?

Comment: I'm sorry, how you define $k[r_1, r_2]?$

Comment: So you need a counterexample, $k[xy,xz]\subset k[x,y,z]$($k$ is a field, and $k[x,y,z]$ is the polynomial ring over $k$ in three variables $x,y,z$, and $k[xy,xz]$ is the subring of $k[x,y,z]$ generated by $xy,xz$ and the field $k$). Now set $r_1=xy,r_2=xz$.

Comment: $k[r_1,r_2]=\{f(r_1,r_2)| f(t_1,t_2)\in k[t_1,t_2]\}$ where $k[t_1,t_2]$ is the polynomial ring in two indeterminates over $k$.

Comment: Replace all $k$ by the ring of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ gcds in PIDs D persist in extension rings because the gcd may be specified by the solvability of (linear) equations over D,  and such solutions always persist in extension rings, i.e. roots in D remain roots in rings $\rm\,R \supset D.\:$ More precisely, PIDs enjoy  [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for their gcds, which yields the following ring-theoretic *equational* specification for the gcd

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\gcd(a,b) = c &\iff&\rm (a,b) = (c)\\
&\iff&\rm  a = c\:\color{#C00}x ,\  b= c\:\color{#C00} y ,\,\ a\:\color{#C00} u + b\: \color{#C00}v = c\ \  has\ roots\ \ \color{#C00}{x,y,u,v}\in D\end{eqnarray}$$

**Proof** $\, $ The first equivalence  is proved [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4129049/242) For the second: in any ring $\,\rm R,\,$  $\rm\,a\, x = c,\ b\, y = c\,$ have roots $\rm\,x,y\in R$ $\iff$ $\rm c\ |\ a,b\,$ in $\rm R\!$ $\rm \iff\! (c)\supseteq (a,b).\,$ Reversely $\,\rm(c)\subseteq (a,b)\iff$ $\rm c\in (a,b) \iff c = a\,u + b\,v\,$ for some $\rm \,u,v\in R.\ $ **QED**

Rings with such linearly representable gcds are known as *Bezout* rings. As above, gcds in such rings always persist in extension rings. In particular, coprime elements remain coprime in extension rings (with same $1$). This need not be true without such Bezout linear representations of the gcd. For example, $\rm\:\gcd(2,x) = 1\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x]\:$ but the gcd is the nonunit  $\:2\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x/2]\subset \mathbb Q[x]$. The above proof fails because there is no Bezout equation $\rm\, 2\,f + x\,g = 1,\,$ else $\rm\,2\, f(0) = 1\,$ by eval at $\rm\,x = 0$.

Comment: Note: the gcd "equalities" should really by "associate to" but I'd like the answer to stay accessible to beginners so I leave that simple translation for more advanced readers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof.

Let $()_S$ and $()_R$ denote the ideal generated by the thing inside the parentheses in $S$ and $R$ respectively. As $a$ is a GCD of $r_1$ and $r_2$ in $R$, $(a)_R = (r_1,r_2)_R$. Now if $e\mid r_1$ and $e\mid r_2$ in $S$, then $(r_1,r_2)_S \subset (e)_S$. Obviously, $(r_1,r_2)_R \subset (r_1,r_2)_S$, so we get $(a)_R \subset (e)_S$, thus $a \in (e)_S$ so $e \mid a$ in $S$. And of course $a\mid r_1$ and $a\mid r_2$ in $S$. Therefore $a$ is a GCD in $S$ as well.