# An irreducible polynomial cannot share a root with a polynomial without dividing it

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

There is a lemma of Galois stating, *"An irreducible equation can have no common root with a rational equation without dividing it"*.

His definitions are a little bit imprecise, but I think he means:

> Let $P, Q\in \Bbb K[X]$, $P$ irreducible. Then if $P$ shares a root with $Q$, $P$ divides $Q$.

His only gesture towards a proof is *"Since the greatest common divisor of $P$ and $Q$ would be rational* [would be in $\Bbb K[X]$] *, therefore, etc."*.

Can I have a modern proof, or at least a stronger hint at a proof? All I can see is that if $a$ is a common root to $P$ and $Q$, then $X-a$ would divide them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be the minimal polynomial of the common root.
Then $R$ divides every polynomial having this root, esp. $R$ divides both $P$ and $Q$. So $P=RS$, $Q=RT$ with some polynomials $S,T$.
As $P$ is irreducible, one of $R,S$ must be a unit and $R$ cannot be a unit.
Thus $Q=RTS^{-1}$ shows that $P$ divides $Q$.

Comment: Do you mean $Q=RTSS^{-1}$?

Answer (score 6):

Let $D$ be "the" gcd of $P$ and $Q$. Since $P$ is irreducible, $D$ is either $P$ or $1$.

We show that $D$ cannot be $1$. If $D=1$, there are polynomials $X$ and $Y$ such that $PX+QY=1$. This is impossible, since any common root of $P$ and $Q$ is a root of $PX+QY$, and the polynomial $1$ has no root.

Comment: Why would $D$ have to have a root? Is it that any common divisor divides the GCD, in particular $X-a$?

Comment: I have added a line of detail (gcd is a linear combination).

Answer (score 2):

**Key Idea** $\ $ The gcd $\,(a,b) = c\,$ *persists* in extension domains when it is *linearly* representable, i.e. when $\,ar+bs = c,\,$ for some $\,r,s\,$ i.e. when a Bezout identity exists. In particular,  if $\,a,b\,$ are coprime in $D\,$ then they remain coprime in every extension domain $\,E\supset D.\,$ Indeed, if $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1\,$ in $D\,$ then by hypothesis  $\,ar+bs = 1\,$ for some $\,r,s\in D.\,$ Thus if $\,d\mid a,b\,$ in $E\,$ then $\,d\mid ar+bs = 1,\,$ so $\,a,b\,$  remain coprime in $\,E,\,$ i.e. *coprimality persists in extensions*.

In your case $\,P,Q\,$ are not coprime in an extension domain since they have a common root $\,\alpha\,$ hence  a common factor $\,X-\alpha.\,$ Therefore, by above, $\,P\,$ and $\,Q\,$ are not coprime in $\,D = \Bbb K[X],\,$ i.e. $\,\gcd(P,Q)\neq 1\,$ thus, since $P$ is irreducible, $\,\gcd(P,Q) = P,\,$  hence $\,P\mid Q.$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242) for further discussion of the key idea of *gcd persistence* in extension rings of Euclidean domains (or, more generally, Bezout domains or PIDs).