# On Bezout's identity

Tags: polynomials

Assume $F$ is a field. Then for each $f,g\in F[x]$ with greatest common divisor $(f,g)=d$ by Bezout's identity $uf+vg=d$ for some $u,v\in F[x]$.

How can we see that $(u,v)=1$?

Furthermore, if for some $h,r\in F[x]$ we have $hf+rg=1$, how can we see that $(f,g)=1$?

And lastly, if $g$ is not associated to $f$, how can we find unique Bezout coefficients $u,v$ such that $\deg u\leq\deg g-\deg (f,g)-1$ and $\deg v\leq\deg f-\deg (f,g)-1$?

Are those statements true in any Bezout ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part first, because the first part follows from it.

If $d|f$ and $d|g$, then $d|hf + rg$, so $d|1$. Hence $(f,g) = 1$

Now for the first part: if $(u,v) = e > 1$, then $e  | uf + vg = d $, so $\frac{u}{e}f + \frac{v}{e}g = \frac{d}{e}$. So by the above, we must have $(f,g) | \frac{d}{e}$

Answer (score 0):

If $e|u$, $e|v$ then $e|d$

$\therefore e|f$, $e|g$

$\therefore e^2|d$

$\therefore e^2|f$, $e^2|g$

$e^n|d \ \forall n$, contradiction

For your second question suppose $e|f$, $e|g$ then $e|1$

Both argument do work in any Bezout ring, there are no requirements really.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{eqnarray} {\bf Hint}\ \ \ (a,b)\mid a,b &&\Rightarrow\ (a,b)\mid ua+vb\\ 
(u,v)\mid u,v\! &&\Rightarrow\ (u,v)\mid ua+vb\end{eqnarray}$

Hence applying the above to $\ u\dfrac{f}d + v \dfrac{g}d\, =\, \color{#c00}1\ $ yields $\,(u,v)\mid \color{#c00}1.\,$

You can find the Bezout coefficients using the [Extended Euclidean algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#85841)

The divisibility inference holds true in any ring, i.e, any common divisor of *linear* form is necessarily greatest (i.e. divisible by all common divisors), [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242) for further discussion.