# $A+A^2B+B=0$ implies $A^2+I$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices over a field such that $A+A^2B+B=0$.
Is it true that $A^2+I$ is always invertible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By taking the transpose, this is equivalent to asking whether $A + BA^2 + B = 0$ implies $A^2+I$ invertible. $(A^2+I)v = 0$ for some vector. Then $0 = (A + BA^2 + B) v = Av + B(A^2+I)v = Av$, therefore $v = (A^2+I)v = 0$. Therefore $A^2+I$ has trivial kernel and is invertible.

Answer (score 27):

We have $A+(A^2+I)B=0$. We multiply by $A$:

$$A^2+(A^2+I)BA=0$$

We add $I$:

$$I+A^{2}+(A^2+I)BA=I=(A^2+I)(I+BA)$$
 Hence $A^2+I$ is invertible, and its inverse is $I+BA$.

Comment: See my answer for a very simple way to motivate this, including *discovering* the inverse (if need be).

Answer (score 2):

${\bf Hint}\  \ 1\!+\!aa\mid \color{#c00}a\,\Rightarrow\, 1\!+\!aa \mid 1 = 1\!+\!aa-\color{#c00}aa,\ $ e.g. applying this to the special case at hand:

$\quad\ \ \color{#0a0}{{-}(1\!+\!aa)b} =  \color{#c00}{a},\ $ hence $\ 1 = 1\!+\!aa-\color{#c00}{a}a = 1\!+\!aa\color{#0a0}{+(1\!+\!aa)b}a=(1\!+\!aa)(1\!+\!ba) $

**Remark** $\ $ Essentially we exploit the [universality of the Bezout identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242) $\,1\!+\!aa-\color{#c00}aa = 1.$

Comment: Why $1 + aa \mid a \implies 1 + aa \mid 1$? (I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: @aximut Since $\,1\!+\!aa\,$ divides $\,1\!+\!aa\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}a,\,$ it divides $\,1\!+\!aa -\color{#c00}aa,\,$ e.g. see the explicit proof of the special case above.