# Integer coprime over $\mathbb Z$ but have common factor over an GCD Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

We known integers can split differently in GCD domains.

Given coprime $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ is it possible that they have a common (possibly unit) factor in a GCD domain?

Answer (score 3):

No. If $a,b$ are coprime in $\mathbb Z$, then for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ we have $ax+by=1$. This relation will still hold in any other ring containing $\mathbb Z$, so if $a,b$ had any common nonunit factor, it would divide $1$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the Bezout identity in $\Bbb Z$ persists in any ring, i.e. $\,ja+kb = 1$ so $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1$

Generally [GCDS in a PID persist in any extension domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242)

Comment: Unit factors are OK?

Comment: @Brout It's not clear what you mean.  Generally GCDs are defined only up to unit factors.