# Euclidean Algorithm in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm, polynomial-rings

I've been tasked with finding an element $d\in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $$(d)=(x^4-x^2+4x, x^3-x+3).$$ To do this, I'm confused at what exactly I'm meant to do to find this element. First I did the algorithm on the two polynomials:
$$x^4-x^2+4x = (x^3-x+3)(x)+(x)\\
x^3-x+3=(x)(x^2-1)+3\\
x=(3)\left(\frac 1 3 x\right)+(0)$$

Does this mean that my (d) is just 1? Or have I misunderstood something, because in this case, the last nonzero remainder must be 1. And if I use backwards substitution, I get that
$$\left(-\frac 1 3 x^2+\frac 1 3\right)\left(x^4-x^2+4x)+\right(\frac 1 3-\frac 1 3 x + \frac 1 3)\left(x^3-x+3\right)=1 $$ which seems to check out.

Have I misunderstood what is meant with finding $d$? This feels weirdly easy.

Comment: You [got it right](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialGCD%28x%5E4-x%5E2%2B4%5Ex%2Cx%5E3-x%2B3%29).

Comment: @Christoph Neat, thank you very much. I'm curious, using this, can I find if $((x^4-x^2+4x, x^3-x+3)$ is a principal ideal of $\mathbb Z[i]$? I think we had a theorem about something similar to this, I'm not sure how it went anymore.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: you can consider $(x^4-x^2+4x,x^3-x+3)$ as an ideal in $\mathbb Q[x]$, where it is equal to $\mathbb Q$, or as an ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$, where it is equal to $(3)=3\mathbb Z[x]$. There is no $x$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Anyhow, this should be a new question.

Comment: @Christoph You are right, I meant to say $\mathbb Z[x]$. I will post a further thread for clarification once the timer is up.  Thank you :)

Comment: No need to ask,  it's already proved here in many places, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242).