# Prove: If $m^2 + n^2 \equiv_{4}{0}$ and $7n + 5m =2$ then $(n,m) = 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $m,n$ be a integers such that $m^2 + n^2 \equiv_{4}{0}$.
>
> Prove:
>
> If $7n + 5m =2$ then $(n,m) = 2$.

I was able to show that $m, n$ are both even.

Im not so sure how to continue. Any hints will be useful.

Comment: By [here in the dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242) $\,\gcd(n,m) = 2\iff 2\mid n,m\,$ & $\,\color{#c00}an+\color{#c00}bm = 2\,$ for some integers $\,\color{#c00}{a,b}.\,$ That's true: $\,\color{#c00}7n+\color{#c00}5m = 2\,$ (and you proved $\,2\mid n,m$). This **Bezout equational specification of the gcd** is precisely what you need to complete your proof. This gcd characterization works not only in $\Bbb Z\,$ but in every every Euclidean domain or PID, e.g. $\,\Bbb Z[i],\ \Bbb Q[x],\,$ etc. But not in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ or $\Bbb Q[x,y].\ \ $

Comment: Note: question was originally tagged 'abstract-algebra' so I injected  a bit of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach.

If $x$ is odd, then $x^2 \equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  By the constraints of the problem, you can therefore conclude that

$$\text{both} ~m,n~ \text{are even}.\tag1 $$

Further, as a general rule, if you take any linear combination $Am + Bn = C$, then the gcd$(m,n) = d$ must be a divisor of $C$.  This follows, since $d|m$ and $d|n$ implies that $d$ divides any linear combination involving $m,n$.

Therefore

$$\text{gcd}(m,n) ~\text{is a divisor of} ~2. \tag2 $$

The conclusion follows by putting (1) and (2) above together.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : For all integer $n$, $n^2\equiv_4 0, 1$. So $n, m$ should be all even. Then?

> Since $5\not\mid n$, so $(n, m)=(n, 5m)=(n, 5m+7n)=(n, 2)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to show that m,n are both even.

That's a great start. This means that $2$ divides both $m$ and $n$, hence divides their gcd $d=(m,n)$.

Now, $7n+5m=2$ implies that $d$ divides $2$, so $d=2$. Indeed, $d$ divides both $n$ and $m$, so it has to divides $7n$ and $5m$, and their sum $7n+5m=2$.