# Bezout Lemma in a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

The Bezout Lemma in the integers states that

> For any $a, b \in\mathbb Z$, let $g = \gcd(a, b)$, There exists $x, y$ such that $ax+by = g$.

This can be generalized to a commutative ring that is a principal ideal domain (PID).

> For any $a, b$ in a PID $R$, let $g = \gcd(a, b)$, which is defined by multiplying the common factors in their unique factorization (hence it is defined up to associates), then:
>
> 1. There exists $x, y$ such that $ax+by = g$.
> 2. The ideals generated by $a, b$ and $g$ respectively are the same: $(a, b) = (g)$

For the above setup, can we say $\gcd(x, y) = 1$? I think this is true (at least in the integers), but I got stuck when I tried to prove it.

---

My Proof Attempt: Say by contradiction that $\gcd(x, y) \ne 1$, then I can write $x = q\bar x, y = q\bar y$ for some non-unit $q$, then
$$ax+by = g \Leftrightarrow q(a\bar x + b\bar y)=g$$
Obviously the element $a\bar x+b \bar y \in(a, b)=(g)$...

---

To complete the proof I need the fact that since $(a, b) = (g)$, $q$ has to be a unit. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: From what you've written, it seems you want to prove that the gcd in a PID is always 1, which is not the case. Am I misreading something?

Comment: See [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713332/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: I want to ask whether $gcd(x, y) = 1$, I think the above proof shows gcd(a, b) = 1?